# i need help in one to many insert using hibernate

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, one-to-many

iam new here and i want your help

iam trying to make a one to many mapping using hibernate 
i have a company table and this table relation to other table 
brnahes 
so one company may have many branshes

so i make a one to many mapping and write a code and its work

this is my DAO code

public class companyDAO {

```
public String createCompany(companyDTO cDto) {

    SessionHelper sessionHelper = new SessionHelper();
    Session session = sessionHelper.getSession();

    session.beginTransaction();
    session.persist(cDto);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();

    return "Company Table Created Succesfully";
}
```

}

and this is my main :

```
    companyDTO cdto = new companyDTO();
    cdto.setcName("Profix");
    cdto.setcEmail("po@gmail.com");
    cdto.setcPhone("07808551147");
    cdto.setcNbransh(3);

    branshesDTO bdtomain = new branshesDTO();
    bdtomain.setbName("profect");
    bdtomain.setbPhone("0788965452");
    bdtomain.setbEmail("pr@gmail.com");
    bdtomain.setbLocation("Amman");

    branshesDTO bdto2 = new branshesDTO();
    bdto2.setbName("Leeg");
    bdto2.setbPhone("0095622232");
    bdto2.setbEmail("lee@gmail.com");
    bdto2.setbLocation("Amman");

    List<branshesDTO> branshesDTOs = new ArrayList<branshesDTO>();
    branshesDTOs.add(bdtomain);
    branshesDTOs.add(bdto2);

    cdto.setDtos(branshesDTOs);
    companyDAO cdao = new companyDAO();

    String res = cdao.createCompany(cdto);
    System.out.println("Res:" + res);
```

and this is my hbm.xml file :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mago2.png)

so now my  code here when i want to add company 
i add its branshes together

so  now after i make a company and one bransh

then if i want to add another branshes related to the same company id

how can i add ??

this is my sql table fro company after apply the code 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CL47W.png)

and this is my table of branshes :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRfCB.png)

so as you see in the table of bransh for cid 1 i have two branshes

so how i can add another bransh for the company id 1

without define a new company in company table ??

i want to add company in one function 
and to add bransh on another function   not together

how i can do That ??

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions. I suggest reading [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Too many questions

Answer (score 0):

first you can set in you mapping file

```
 <set name="dtos" inverse="true" cascade="all">
```

The “inverse” keyword is always declare in one-to-many and many-to-many relationship , it means which side is responsible to take care of the relationship.

and about adding multiple branches in one company without declaring new company

you can make a method that take primary key of company as argument and presist this company then you can add your branch

for example in your dto add

```
 public void addBranch(BranchDTO branchDTO ){
    branchDTO .setCompanyDto(this);
    dtos.add(branchDTO);
}
```

and you can add new branch in existing company with this
you can presist company with its id

```
public void addANewBranch(BranchDTO branchDTO, Integer companyDtoId) {

    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    try {

        session.getTransaction().begin();
        CompanyDto com= session.get(CompanyDto .class,companyDtoId);
         com.addBranch(branchDTO);
        session.update(com);
        session.getTransaction().commit();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        session.getTransaction().rollback();
        logger.error("Error occurredr. Error stack trace: " + e.toString());
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
```

in main class you can call this method

```
BranchDTO branchDTO = new BranchDTO ("your fields values");
yourobjectDao.addANewBranch(branchDTO , your company id)
```

i think this will help
[child and parent relationship](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/example-parentchild.html)

after i write this code on my main :

```
branshesDTO bdtoo = new branshesDTO();
companyDAO comdao = new companyDAO();

bdtoo.setbName("bbffffbbb");
bdtoo.setbPhone("215f51");
bdtoo.setbEmail("s@gmail.com");
bdtoo.setbLocation("jhhhhjj");
comdao.addANewBranch(bdtoo, 1);
```

and run it, I get this exception on my console:

```
Mar 29, 2018 1:05:41 PM org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.stax.LocalXmlResourceResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH90000012: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping instead.  Support for obsolete DTD/XSD namespaces may be removed at any time.
Mar 29, 2018 1:05:41 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Mar 29, 2018 1:05:41 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/omartest]
Mar 29, 2018 1:05:41 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
Mar 29, 2018 1:05:41 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
Mar 29, 2018 1:05:41 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Thu Mar 29 13:05:41 EET 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Mar 29, 2018 1:05:41 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
Mar 29, 2018 1:05:42 PM org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl getIsolatedConnection
INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@7e1a1da6] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
```

so now what i have to do ??

Comment: so you want me to put  this 
addBranch
in my CompanyDto class ?? 

and put 
addANewBranch
in my DAO class ?? 

so what i must write in my main ??

Comment: using this with be to get refrence for your company by its id, and then call this function by your new branch and your company

Comment: mmm sorry i know i asked a lot but iam new and can you show me how this code will be on my main ??

Comment: realy iam very sorry 
 i write this on my main : 

  branshesDTO bdtoo = new branshesDTO();
  companyDAO comdao = new companyDAO();

  bdtoo.setbName("bbffffbbb");
  bdtoo.setbPhone("21551");
  bdtoo.setbEmail("s@gmail.com");
  bdtoo.setbLocation("jhhhhjj");
  comdao.addANewBranch(bdtoo, 1);

and run the code its run but nothing happend to the branshes table on mysql ? 
what i have to do ?

Comment: this is the exception on console after run

Comment: i edit the question above and write to you the exception on my console after run this code 

what i have to do ??

Comment: all i see in console are info were is the exception

Comment: i but this 
catch (Exception e) {
         session.getTransaction().rollback();
         System.out.println("error");

and when i run the code 
i find the word (error) 
also nothing happend to the bransh table ?? 
no new record happend 
what the wrong ? 
and why we dont use the method

 public void addBranch(BranchDTO branchDTO ){
    branchDTO .setCompanyDto(this);
    dtos.add(branchDTO);
}

that you want me to put in company dto class ?

Comment: to see exception you can print exception stack trace

Comment: this is the exception ? 

java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.dms.dao.companyDAO.addANewBranch(companyDAO.java:32)
 at com.dms.main.test.main(test.java:139)

what i have to edit ??

Comment: he says we have null poimnter at this line 

         companyDTO com= session.get(companyDTO .class,companyDTO .getcId());
          com.addBranch(branchDTO);

Answer (score -1):

firstly based on company name(if it is unique) get company id, then after you can add other branch details to same company. Make sure use session.get method instead of load method... because when we use load method if there is no name with given company you will get object not found exception so better use get method.

Comment: can you write here what the code will be to add new  bransh to company id (1) ? ??